# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$string

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-resources, android-support-library

Iam building an Application which is using the support libraries.

There is no compilation errors on my project but when I run I see this message in the logcat :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$string

Apparently a solution to that was to run an update on the libraries project which i did using the android update command tool, but it did not help.

please click [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpAuX.png) for the full logcat log

Comment: You are using android.support.v7 as jar or as library project?

Comment: Hello @Jedil, Iam using it as a library using the Project Reference and also I have a jar file inside Android Private Libraries

Comment: But is mediaRouter in separate project which your main project is using as library project?

Comment: It is on a separate project in the same workspace. Please look here http://i.imgur.com/WO5H57F.png

Comment: But in 'android private libraries'  you are using mediarouter.jar from your main project, not from library project

Comment: Are you using v4 support libraries as well?

Comment: Can you include the `<uses-sdk>` section of your configuration?

Comment: @jedil you are right but Iam trying to change it and I cant..Any idea how to do that!?

Comment: Add your android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar to `libs` folder of `android-support-v7-mediarouter` library project

Comment: @jedil ok I managed to delete that jar file, but when I copy it from the android support project it still shows that is coming from the android.slideshow project..WHY?

Comment: @jedil I want the jar of the android-support-mediarouter to be added to android.slideshow

Comment: [link ](http://i.imgur.com/kv5jZ99.png?1?9723)

Comment: FIXED the buildpaths! Thanks JEDIL!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than referencing the JAR file for the library , you should reference the library's source code directly.